# Smart way to make all UI elements firing their initial values?

Tags: ios, user-interface, triggers

I'm designing sound applications with (sometimes HUGE) UI filled of UISlider & UISwitch.
I'm storing values only in the UI elements, because my sound part doesn't need to store it on its own (it is simplier & lighter like that)
So, I'd like to know if there was a smart way to trigger ALL UI elements of a view in order to initialize some values easily at the viewDidLoad time.

Best,
ju

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make all of your UI elements IBOutlet @properties of your view controller. If you are using storyboards, drag from the UI elements to the view controller's .h file, and select "outlet"

Then in your viewDidLoad method you can get the values of each element. You can get the value of a UISlider, for example, by doing:

```
slider.value
```

Comment: Hi there. thanks. Yes indeed, I got that. But What would be the best practices way to "fire" all values at a time? Indeed, I can create a huge list : myVar = [mySlider value]; But just wanted to figure out if I could trigger this on another way.

Comment: IMO that's the cleanest way. However, you could grab the parent view and then call subviews on it to get an array of it's subviews. Iterate through those, check the type of each, and get the values for the appropriate elements.